# Return compound literal

Tags: c, standards, undefined-behavior, compound-literals, storage-duration

Look at this code. I return an address of the compound literal here.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define FOO(bar) ((bar)->a + (bar)->b)

struct bar {
    int a;
    int b;
};

static struct bar * to_bar(int a, int b);

int main(void)
{
    int baz = FOO((struct bar *) {to_bar(1, 2)});

    printf("%d\n", baz);

    return 0;
}

static struct bar *
to_bar(int a, int b)
{
    return &(struct bar) {a, b};
}
```

Output:

```
3
```

ISO/IEC 9899 says:

> If the compound literal occurs outside the body of a function, the
> object has static storage duration; otherwise, it has automatic
> storage duration associated with the enclosing block.

I. e., in the `to_bar` function the unnamed object, created by the compound literal has automatic storage duration. Thereby, it will be destroyed outside scope of `to_bar`. It seems, this code produces undefined behaviour (based on the standard). Is it so?

Comment: That's right, it is UB. For your [mcve] you could use a bit less obfuscated code though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. In your example, you immediately retrieved the fields after returning from `to_bar`, so you didn't have time to corrupt the stack frame of the deceased `to_bar` function. But here's another example:

```
struct bar {
    int a;
    int b;
};

static struct bar * to_bar(int a, int b);

int main(void)
{

    struct bar * corrupted_bar = to_bar(1, 2);

    printf("this print will corrupt\n");

    int baz = corrupted_bar->a + corrupted_bar->b;

    printf("baz = %d\n", baz);

    return 0;
}

static struct bar *
to_bar(int a, int b)
{
    return &(struct bar) {a, b};
}
```

which when executed

```
this print will corrupt
baz = -59543507
```

If you look at the assembly

```
.LC0:
        .string "this print will corrupt"
.LC1:
        .string "baz = %d\n"
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16
        mov     esi, 2
        mov     edi, 1
        call    to_bar                    ; call to_bar
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rax    ; save address returned to a local pointer
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0     ; argument into puts()
        call    puts                      ; call puts(), which creates its own local variables that corrupts the bar struct
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]    
        mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rax]
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rax+4]
        add     eax, edx
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-12], eax
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]
        mov     esi, eax
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC1
        mov     eax, 0
        call    printf
        mov     eax, 0
        leave
        ret
to_bar:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-20], edi
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-24], esi
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-20]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], eax     ; field 'a' gets stored, notice dest addr rbp-8 is in the stack frame of this function (local variable)
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-24]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], eax     ; field 'b' gets stored, same as above
        lea     rax, [rbp-8]
        pop     rbp
        ret
```